# iOS UDK Kismet Compare Vectors?

Tags: ios, udk

I have created a control scheme identical to the UDK Jazz Jackrabbit tutorial.

Everything works as it should except I would like the Left Stick to control the character rotation when the Right Stick is not being pressed.

I'm terribly stumped here as don't know whether I should be comparing the vector output or the active/inactive input... nor do I honestly know how do this in Kismet :)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:
I want the left stick to do both the movement and rotation... until the right stick is pressed. In Kismet, how do I override the left stick's input with the right stick when it is pressed? (for the rotation that is)

Comment: Is this possible with Kismet or do I need to use unrealscript? I would prefer Kismet in this instance...

Comment: I worry about the prerequisites to answering: To answer, I'd have to know UDK, Kismet and the UDK Jazz Jackrabbit tutorial. Is there a way to generalise this question?

Comment: Hey Anko... I know exactly what you mean. I'll try my best to generalize it in an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: left stick rotation]

It's dirty... but it works. Hopefully in the future I'll find a better solution. IE build everything in UnrealScript.